# Add drop-down column in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

I want to create a column in a data grid that displays a drop-down list. I want the `unit` column to have a drop-down with the following values: *%*, *m/hr*, *mm* . How can I do this in code-behind?

```
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
DataColumn description = new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string));
DataColumn unit = new DataColumn("Unit", typeof(string));
DataColumn case1 = new DataColumn("Case 1", typeof(string));
DataColumn case2 = new DataColumn("Case 2", typeof(string));
DataColumn case3 = new DataColumn("Case 3", typeof(string));
DataColumn case4 = new DataColumn("Case 4", typeof(string));
DataColumn case5 = new DataColumn("Case 5", typeof(string));
DataColumn case6 = new DataColumn("Case 6", typeof(string));
DataColumn max = new DataColumn("Max", typeof(string));

dt.Columns.Add(description);
dt.Columns.Add(unit);
dt.Columns.Add(case1);
dt.Columns.Add(case2);
dt.Columns.Add(case3);
dt.Columns.Add(case4);
dt.Columns.Add(case5);
dt.Columns.Add(case6);
dt.Columns.Add(max);

dt.Rows.Add("Mist fraction - predicted", "%", "0.00", "0.00");
dt.Rows.Add(" ", " ", " ", " "," "," ");
dt.Rows.Add("Mist flow rate", "m/hr", "0.00", "0.00");

dataGrid2.ItemsSource = dt2.DefaultView;
```

```xaml
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" ColumnWidth="*"/>
```

Comment: You can use either a comboboxcolumn or templatecolumn with a combobox in it. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26347.wpf-combobox-binding-in-datagrid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To display cells with a combo box, you have to use a [`DataGridComboBoxColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn?view=netcore-3.1) in the `DataGrid`. The WPF `DataGrid` by default automatically generates columns for your items source. You can hook into the [AutoGeneratingColumn event](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns?view=netcore-3.1) to replace the `Unit` data column with a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, when the columns are being generated.

This is your original code put into a method and cleaned up. It adds an event handler to the auto-generating column event.

```
private void Create()
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    var description = new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string));
    var unit = new DataColumn("Unit", typeof(string));
    var case1 = new DataColumn("Case 1", typeof(string));
    var case2 = new DataColumn("Case 2", typeof(string));
    var case3 = new DataColumn("Case 3", typeof(string));
    var case4 = new DataColumn("Case 4", typeof(string));
    var case5 = new DataColumn("Case 5", typeof(string));
    var case6 = new DataColumn("Case 6", typeof(string));
    var max = new DataColumn("Max", typeof(string));

    dataTable.Columns.Add(description);
    dataTable.Columns.Add(unit);
    dataTable.Columns.Add(case1);
    dataTable.Columns.Add(case2);
    dataTable.Columns.Add(case3);
    dataTable.Columns.Add(case4);
    dataTable.Columns.Add(case5);
    dataTable.Columns.Add(case6);
    dataTable.Columns.Add(max);

    dataTable.Rows.Add("Mist fraction - predicted", "%", "0.00", "0.00");
    dataTable.Rows.Add(" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ");
    dataTable.Rows.Add("Mist flow rate", "m/hr", "0.00", "0.00");

    // Hook into the event to replace the column
    dataGrid2.AutoGeneratingColumn += OnAutoGeneratingColumn;
    dataGrid2.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
}
```

This is the event handler to replace the `Unit` column.

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object? sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
 {
     if(e.Column.Header.Equals("Unit"))
     {
         // These are the drop-down items
         var units = new List<string> { "%", "m/hr", "mm" };

         // Create a new combo-box column
         var unitColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn
         {
             Header = e.Column.Header,
             ItemsSource = units,
             SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("Unit")
         };

         // Replace the auto-generated column
         e.Column = unitColumn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Datacolumn is a column in a data TABLE. And the default for a datagrid is to auto generate columns. You also need to set that to false on the datagrid and add all the columns including the datagridcomboboxcolumn explicitly to the columns collection of the datagrid.

Comment: @Andy Sorry, you are right. I have adapted the answer accordingly using the given sample.